# How to set Count function field of select query in crystal report detail section?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports, select-query

I want to display rows that contain count() field with group by clause, How can we set programmatically this on crystal report on run time in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just put a field whose count you need in detail section. Then either use runningtotal factility or use a formula

```
Count ({Table.Value})
```

Please check below link.

[In Crystal Reports, How do I count all the rows in the Details section and place that count in the header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697022/in-crystal-reports-how-do-i-count-all-the-rows-in-the-details-section-and-place)

http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=11297